# How do I use a range of numbers in if, elif, else functions in Python

Tags: python

Here's my code.

```
def function():
    rng = randint(1,10)
    if rng == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5:
        print "option 1"
    elif rng == 6:
        print "option 2"
    elif rng == 7:
        print "option 3"
    else:
        print "option 4"
```

In the blank space in the if statement, I want the code to consider if rng equals a range of integers from 1 to 5. When I run this function, it always prints out "option 1", leading me to believe there's something wrong with the if statement, causing the code to automatically print option 1 and discard all other code. Is there another way to express "if rng == 1 to 5"?

Comment: `if rng in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: or in this case `if rng <= 5`

Comment: @khelwood nice one.

Comment: in that particular case `range(1,6)` would be even faster than `[1,2,3,4,5]` because values are consecutive and `range` (python 3) does not generate the list, it just checks the bounds.

Comment: For future reference: `if rng == 1 or 2…` should most certainly be `if rng == 1 or rng == 2…`